# customize iphone settings programmatically

Tags: iphone, settings

I have an application in which, after running it and selecting setting of iPhone, inside the application name, there should be a button.

I know that through settings.bundle we cannot add a button.

So is there some way to do it programmatically?

Or else can we add a uitableviewcell to settings same like safari and all so that it looks like a button?

Please guide me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not have the same control over the settings as the built-in apps. Also, since you can't run any code from within the settings app, what should your button do? (Though I imagine a URL-based button could be useful in some cases).

Comment: ok.. thanks for your input.. but there is no way to programatically alter iPhone settings?

Comment: Yes, but only from within your app.

Comment: yes from within my app, how can i do it?

Comment: Look at @Shelm's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900916/adding-a-button-to-an-iphone-prefs-settings-bundle) it is not possible. 
If you are not bound to use the iPhone system settings you may have a look at the [inAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/home)