# How add button in settings.bundle in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, application-settings, settings.bundle

I am using settings.bundle in my iOS app but problem is how to add button in that page and handling that button. Can any body help me on this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900916/adding-a-button-to-an-iphone-prefs-settings-bundle

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You cant run code in setting bundle. So it is useless. The system only supports interacting with the values from within your app.

Comment: But nike+ipod,facebook,twitter apps have this functionality

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do there is to include a list of options. There are apps like Netflix which have a kind of "action button". They implement a radio control (boolean) to reset their options. So when the app starts again it checks for the value of the property and it deletes everything if the radio is set to yes.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)